# What do "Shot Caller" and "Expendable" mean in a social war game? Which is higher?

Tags: slang

I've been recently playing a social game so deep like below.

[image]

We form a "Guild" and combat with each other, comprising of 15 members, like taking down castles or towers sort of thing.

Each member has a "rank".

"Guild Master" decides who attacks which "enemy" in the war. So he is the literal boss.

I would like to ask, who would be a "Shot Caller"? And the "Expendable"?

I googled by "Shot Caller Meaning" but ended up in [**these definitions.**](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/shot-caller)

It seems that the shot-callers are kind of a boss of some gang members or that kind, but in this game, the Guild Master is the boss as below. Would native speakers call a pure "member" just a "shot-caller"?

And does anybody have any thoughts about the difference between shot-caller and the expendable?

Any opinions/ideas are welcome.

My team's ranking is very easy.

[image]

Guild Master > General > Officer > Member

Thank you.

Comment: These words have defined meanings in the context of the game and are only loosely connected to their meaning in the language generally.

Comment: I take it that each guild defines its own titles?  Generally I'd assume the Shot Caller is the commander (in an artillery unit it would be literal).  An ‘Expendable’ in a guild named ‘The Expendables’ presumably is a member with no special office; in general it describes a low-ranking soldier who can be sent to his death with little regret.

Comment: @AntonSherwood Thanks for the info. Either way, as the answer suggests, I stopped thinking so deep......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks to me like a poor word choice by a game designer, so not worth thinking too much about.

That said, the expression, to "call the shots" means to make the important during the action, so being a "shot caller" would ordinarily mean "leader" at some level. It's also a slang expression for a fairly high-up gang member. None of the definitions you linked indicate they're the top boss. So I'd guess somewhere between Guild Master and Officer.

Comment: Thank you anyway. It's another's team and this is the game probably I take the words as they are. Thank you really.