# ”At the war" or "In the war"?

Tags: prepositions

As I asked [**previously,**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/285707/what-do-shot-caller-and-expendable-mean-in-a-social-war-game-which-is-highe) I am still deep into the social war game.

When native speakers say something like "I would like to strike the enemy XXXX",
would you use "at the war" or "in the war"?

For example,

"I would like to strike the enemy XXXX **at/in** the war **with YYYYY**"?

Thank you so much(m_m).

Comment: Why do you think that it's necessary to say "at/in the war" at all? Presumably you would say this to somebody who is involved in the same game, so they would know that you don't mean hitting the person over the head with something.

Comment: @JavaLatte Thanks for the comment. But I honestly would like to know from the viewpoint of English as the language as they are....For example, at/in the war with YYYYY.

Comment: I think this question is "legitimate" as a question for a language-English.

Comment: I think the problem is that we are not clear whether this is purely a question about the difference between in war/at war/in the war/at the war or whetheh it can follow the verb striking.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't really understand what the sentence in your question is supposed to mean.

As a general guide, though, you can use **at** relating to the state of war:

> In 1943, Britain was at war with Germany

You can also use **at** with things that are associated with the war, but not the war itself, for example a place:

> He worked at the war department
> I will meet you at the war memorial

or a specific instant (not the entire duration):

> The country was not ready at the war's start

You use **in** relating to involvement in a war:

> This work is divided into two sections...an alphabetical listing of Tennesseans who were Officers in the War of 1812, and an alphabetical listing of the Enlisted Men in the War of 1812. - *Tennesseeans in the war of 1812, Byron & Samuel Sistler, 2007*

or in relation to the period of time in which war was taking place:

> Although this picture conveys essential information about the situation of the family in the war, it remains incomplete. - *The war from within, Ute Daniel, 1997*